# Where did the unit named InvRules (formerly in the SOAP folder) go in Delphi XE2?

Tags: delphi, soap, delphi-xe2

I am trying to port some Delphi XE code to XE2, it uses a unit called InvRules.pas, which according to the XE2 docs, has no namespace prefix.

It also isn't in the soap folder where I expect it:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\source\soap`

The simplest answer is that it's been removed (accidentally or on purpose) from XE2.
Has anyone figured out what's up? This unit contains functions like `GetStackTypeSize`, and RetOnStack, which are used sometimes in custom `TRIOHelper` type classes.

Comment: I can confirm that it's not installed anywhere on my drive related to XE2 Pro SKU. (I have copies for several earlier versions of Delphi).

Comment: I have copied it for now, from XE, and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This unit is no longer used by the soap runtime so it's not being shipped anymore.  In previous releases, it was part of the soaprtl runtime package. There were some significant changes made to the soap runtime for the XE2 release to make the code portable to x64 and less reliant on BASM code that was essentially duplicated in the RTTI support units.  The change log entry associated with the commit states:

> Refactor out InvRules, use RTTI to get type sizes. 
>   Remove InvRules, PrivateHeap from soap package.

If you have code which relies on the helper routines in this unit you should be fine using the source from a previous release.  You may also want to diff the Invoker.pas, InvokeRegistry.pas, OPToSOAPDomConv.pas and Rio.pas units between XE and XE2 to see how the code changed so it no longer relies on the InvRules.pas unit.

Comment: Thanks Mark.  You might want to ping the doc team and tell them to remove references to InvRules, and to write a wiki page about "old RTL units that have been removed".

Comment: Thanks Warren I will do that.  We've streamlined some the process for deciding which source files should be delivered, but keeping the docs in sync (especially for file removals) is still mostly a manual process.